# jQuery script works on local maschine, but not on web host

Tags: javascript, jquery, localhost

I am using [The Final Countdown](http://hilios.github.io/jQuery.countdown/) v2.0.4 , it works just fine on my local machine but on my web host, it doesn't seem to work as intended. Instead of counting down it just immediately goes to 00:00.

jQuery code:

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.countdown.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function()    {
            $(".timeLeft").each(function(i, obj) {
                var $dis = $(this), finalDate = $(this).text().replace("-", "/").replace("-", "/");
                var u = 0;
                $dis.countdown(finalDate, function(event) {
                    $dis.text(event.strftime('%M:%S'));
                    if(event.offset.minutes < 25 && u == 0) {
                        $dis.next().next().find("input[type='image']").attr("src", "images/glyphicons/png/glyphicons-207-ok.png");
                        u++;
                        $dis.next().next().find("input[type='image']").attr("title", "Acceptera uppdraget");
                    }
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
```

Specific HTML code:

```
<thead class="mission_title">
    <tr>
        <td class="timeLeft"><?php echo /*$interval->format("%I:%S")*/ $missions[$i]["expire"]; ?></td>
        <td><form method="post" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]) . "?do=request&id=" . $missions[$i]["id"]; ?>"><input type="number" title="Föreslå ersättning" style="width:35px;" min="<?php echo $missions[$i]["payment"]; ?>" value="<?php echo $missions[$i]["payment"]; ?>" name="price_offer"> <input name="request" type="image" src="<?php echo ($_SESSION["plus"] == 1 ? "images/glyphicons/png/glyphicons-207-ok.png" :  "images/glyphicons/png/glyphicons-208-remove.png"); ?>" alt="Acceptera Uppdraget" title="<?php echo ($_SESSION["plus"] == 1 ? "Acceptera uppdraget." : "Du måste vänta fem minuter innan du kan acceptera uppdraget." );?>" value="send"></td>
    </tr>
</thead>
```

Any help is appreciated, I tried searching and many suggested that case-sensitivity could be an issue; I haven't been able to find anything in the console or by proof-reading my code, so I don't know what the issue is. :(

EDIT:

The jQuery import works fine, I've been using other jQuery functions such as `.click()` and it works without problems.

Comment: This seems rather obvious, but is the jquery.countdown.min.js in the right place on server?

Comment: Yes! The function runs but it doesn't countdown it immediately goes to 00:00

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the class name from "timeLeft" to "time-left".

This is a little bit different approach, but it might make things easier for you.

Have your php script output the target time as a data attribute (use epoch time here; either seconds or milliseconds are fine. I assumed seconds.):

```
<td class="time-left" data-countdown-expire=
<?php echo $missions[$i]["expire"]; ?>
> <!-- rest of td goes here ... -->
```

Then in Javascript, I use the moment library for any kind of time manipulation. It is easy to make it look however you want.

Here's an example that will update your displays each second:

```
setInterval(
function(){ 
var timerNodes = document.getElementsByClassName('time-left');
  var timers = Array.prototype.slice.call(timerNodes)
timers.map(function (el) {
 var endTime = el.getAttribute('data-countdown-expire');
 var timeUntil = moment.unix(endTime).fromNow();
 el.innerHTML = timeUntil;
})
}, 1000);
```

[Codepen example here](http://codepen.io/jkennaly/pen/OMbBPx)

Comment: Thank you, I use strtotime from PHP and then javascript to convert it to local time and it shows the same result on both local machine as well as on my host's server.

Answer (score 0):

I'm stupid,

I never considered that the jQuery would use local timezone; so I have to convert the PHP output to user's timezone since the script doesn't allow me to set timezone for convert.. x_x

Comment: You should consider transferring the time as epoch time, and then using javascript to convert to the local time. Your server will never know for sure what timezone the client is in, and javascript can easily convert epoch time into local time.